# Windows Phone: How to get a contact without using Contacts.SearchAsync task?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, contacts

Is it posible to get a contact without using class Contacts and his SearchAsync method? I proceed to explain my problem.

I have an ObservableCollection

```
private ObservableCollection<ContactPictureItemModel> _ContactPictures;
```

being ContactPictureItemModel something like this

```
public class ContactPictureItemModel
{
    private string _Email;
    private byte[] _Picture;
    private string _DisplayName;

    public ContactPictureItemModel(string email, byte[] picture, string displayName)
    {
        this._Email = email;
        this._Picture = picture;
        this._DisplayName = displayName;
    }

    public string Email
    {
        get { return _Email; }
        set { _Email = value; }
    }

    public byte[] Picture
    {
        get { return _Picture; }
        set { _Picture = value; }
    }

    public string DisplayName
    {
        get { return _DisplayName; }
        set { _DisplayName = value; }
    }
}
```

Every object in this ObservableCollection represents a contact picture that application has "cached" everytime user has picked a contact from EmailAddressChooserTask.

I need when calling this method

```
public ContactPictureItemModel GetContactPictureItem(string email, string displayName)
{
    ContactPictureItemModel contactPictureResult;

    foreach (ContactPictureItemModel contact in ContactPictures)
    {
        if (email.Equals(contact.Key))
        {
            contactPictureResult = contact;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (contactPictureResult == null)
    {
        //Retrieve contact using "email" parameter
    }

    return contactPictureResult;
}
```

and contact is not found in the ObservableCollection, to be able to get the contact using parameters "email" and "displayName" without using any async task. I need the function retrieves the ContactPictureItemModel object.

Is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to synchronously access a contact, since there's no API for it.

You could create the view model in a "loading" state and then "fill it in" when the async method completes. Just make sure the model class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: I dont know what do you mean with "loading state". I'm newbie with Windows Phone and C#. Could you show me an example?

Comment: I just mean having a property `IsLoading` on the model that starts true, setting that to false and filling out the other properties when the data loads.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's working now. I'm gonna explain it in a new answer for anyone interested.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Richard Szalay I found the solution. I'm gonna explain it to help everyone stuck like me in these questions (sorry about Java notation, code is shorter this way)

These are the private fields who has the object that represents a contact and his picture

```
public class ParticipantItemModel {
    private string _Email;
    private string _DisplayName;
    private bool _Paid;
    [XmlIgnore]
    private BitmapImage _ContactPicture;

    [...]
}
```

Every private field has his own property for getting and setting his value. Like this one

```
    public string Email {
        get { return _Email; }
        set { _Email = value; }
    }
```

When dealing with _ContactPicture its properties are a little special. For getting its value, if _ContactPicture is null and the picture isn't cached into the ObservableCollection, I search the contact using the Contacts.SearchAsync task and I return an "empty Image". When the contact is found (despite the view has already been loaded), I set the property ContactPicture with the correct image, raising the PropertyChangedEventArgs event (as you can see at its setter property)

```
    [XmlIgnore]
    public BitmapImage ContactPicture
    {
        get {
            if (_ContactPicture != null) {
                return _ContactPicture;
            } else {
                BitmapImage contactPictureSource = App.ContactPictures.GetContactPicture(Email, DisplayName);

                if (contactPictureSource != null) {
                    return contactPictureSource;
                } else {
                    Contacts contacts = new Contacts();
                    contacts.SearchCompleted += new EventHandler<ContactsSearchEventArgs>(contacts_SearchCompleted);
                    contacts.SearchAsync(DisplayName, FilterKind.DisplayName, Email);

                    return new BitmapImage();
                }
            }
        }

        set {
            _ContactPicture = value;
            //When _ContactPicture is setted, an event is raised by calling to NotifyPropertyChanged()
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ContactPicture");
        }
    }

    void contacts_SearchCompleted(object sender, ContactsSearchEventArgs e) {
        Contact contact = null;

        foreach (var result in e.Results) {
            foreach (ContactEmailAddress contactEmail in result.EmailAddresses) {
                if (Email.Equals(contactEmail.EmailAddress)) {
                    contact = result;
                    this.ContactPicture = GetSourceImageFromContactPicture(contact.GetPicture());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

Also, the INotifyPropertyChanged interface must be implemented in order to raise the event PropertyChangedEventArgs. This event will make the application know the element (the contact's picture) has changed and it will refresh using the binded data

```
public class ParticipantItemModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    [...]

    // Declare the PropertyChanged event
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // NotifyPropertyChanged will raise the PropertyChanged event passing the
    // source property that is being updated.
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

As result, the contact is shown without picture but almost automatically picture is loaded.

I hope it has been helpful